# PHP how to get a random number that is different from values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, random

Example:
I have an array with 3 values:

```
0 = 1
1 = 4
2 = 5
```

I want to get a random number like

```
$random = rand(1, 5);
```

But I need to get a number that is different from the array values. I need it to return 2 or 3.

Comment: So you have a range from where you want to get a random number, but without numbers from your array, right? Also have you tried something?

Comment: So `do { $random = rand(1, 5); } while (in_array($random, $myArray));`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
It worked but I'm getting a Fatal Error sometimes:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: @Rockman Have you read my first comment^ ?

Comment: You're excluding most of the possible random numbers. So sometimes it can take many tries before it picks one that's allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I create the range from where you get your random number with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). Then I get rid of these numbers which you don't want with [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). And at the end you can simply use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random key/number)

```
<?php

    $blacklist = [1, 4, 5];
    $range = range(1, 5);
    $randomArray = array_diff($range, $blacklist);
    echo $randomArray[array_rand($randomArray, 1)];

?>
```

output:

```
2 or 3
```

**EDIT:**

Just did some benchmarks and the method with the loop is much slower than the code above!

I created an array(blacklist) from 1...100'000 and a random number array from      1... 100'001.

So that script should only create one/unique random number. With the loop method you get an error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

And with the posted code above it takes 1.5 sec in average.

Comment: This is much nicer than the loop, it shouldn't cause a time exceeded error.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, That's why I posted it when I saw the possible dupe, since there were no such answer.

Comment: @Barmar Just did some benchmarks and it's a huge difference! (see updated answer)

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks again! It worked just fine, and it is really what i was looking for. I didn't know this array_diff.

Comment: I accepted now, I guess...
This was my first question here in stackoverflow, i'm still learning how to use it, hehe.

Comment: @Rockman no problem, enjoy your day :D (FYI: You can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see a bit how this site works and where everything is)